# SOAP Request using PHP SoapClient not working

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

I am new to SOAP. I am working with a web service organization who needs the following request:

```
POST /bookingapi.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: bookingapitest.globusfamily.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://globusfamily.com/api/booking/ws/internal/GVI_DepartureInfo"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GVI_DepartureInfo xmlns="http://globusfamily.com/api/booking/ws/internal">
      <GVI_DepartureInfoRequest VendorId="string" VendorPassword="string" xmlns="http://globusfamily.com/api/booking/departureinforequest">
        <Brand>string</Brand>
        <TourCode>string</TourCode>
        <DepartureCode>string</DepartureCode>
      </GVI_DepartureInfoRequest>
    </GVI_DepartureInfo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But I cant get this to work. I have tried the following:

```
function test_booking_globus_soap_connect() { 
        $serviceWsdl = 'https://bookingapitest.globusfamily.com/bookingapi.asmx?WSDL';

        $serviceParams = array(
            'login' => "logind",
            'password' => "pw"
        );

        $client = new SoapClient($serviceWsdl, $serviceParams);

        $data['Brand'] = "All";
        $data['TourCode'] = "QBE";
        $data['DepartureCode'] = "800040321";
        $data['VendorId'] = "test";
        $data['VendorPassword'] = "test";

        $results = $client->GVI_DepartureInfo($data);
    }
```

What am i missing? please help.
I am getting this error:
    Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [q0:Security] Security requirements are not satisfied because the security header is not present in the incoming message.

Comment: Hello, I'm using this api and getting same error. have you find out any solutions for this? I need to extract data for : GVI_DepartureInfo

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late response but maybe it will help someone.

You need to include security header into request.

Username and Password are agency Id and password.

Here is example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <UsernameToken>
        <Username>string</Username>
        <Password>string</Password>
      </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GVI_DepartureInfo xmlns="http://globusfamily.com/api/booking/ws/internal">
      <GVI_DepartureInfoRequest VendorId="string" VendorPassword="string" xmlns="http://globusfamily.com/api/booking/departureinforequest">
        <Brand>string</Brand>
        <TourCode>string</TourCode>
        <DepartureCode>string</DepartureCode>
      </GVI_DepartureInfoRequest>
    </GVI_DepartureInfo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```